# How to create a structure for entering complex interrelated data in multiple tables in SQL backend

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I am building an order and invoicing system dealing with services and hardware products. 
Part of the table structure, simplified, is seen below. (Real-life is an order of magnitude more tables):

I would like to select an order from a list of standard-orders, i.e. related to the size of the company, and have the order forms with all the various products related to this standard form be created in the appropriate tables with correct relationships.
As an example: I select a standard order for computers and accessories for a small company of 5 people. The order is created and the OrderItem row(s) also, linked to Order and to Product.

**Customer (subset of Party)**

```
Customer_ID (PK, FK to Party) 
CustomerName
...
```

**Order**

```
Order_ID (PK)
Customer_ID (FK to Customer)
OrderDate
OrderNumber
...
```

**OrderItem**

```
Order_ID (PK, FK to Order)
Product_ID (PK, FK to Product)
Amount
...
```

**Product**

```
Product_ID (PK)
ProductName
Price
Info
...
```

This example is easy to program, but when having maybe ten interrelated tables that needs to be updated - I am not sure what is the best strategy.

Is it best to fetch data in the production tables from:

1) A set of template tables, more or less as a mirror of the production data, interrelated the same way as them but only containing generalized data (standards) and no cols for date, etc?

2) Storing the templates in the production data tables, using an extra field to signify them? This can create a lot of empty cols in those rows, like regarding date etc.

3) Using some other programming method and using that. Like a table calling different stored procedures depending on what template is selected!?

4) ???

Hope this was understandable.

Comment: I'm confused - do you want to store 'standard' orders for new customers (ie - "oh, you're starting a new company, here's our basic business package, plus a few tweaks"), or are you just trying to store the orders in general?  Other: Avoid the use of reserved words for naming things (like `Order`, although alternatives may be clunky there).  Avoid prefixing with the table name (id columns excepted).  Don't use the type when naming a column, name it after it's use - `OrderDate` should probably be `orderedOn` or `createdOn`.

Comment: Hi. Yes, but the 'Standard' package will not only comprise the order itself but many other things related to the company and order, that now must be entered in different tables. I want to be a able to select in a list one of several 'standard' settings, have them entered into multiple tables, and then edited for whatever differs in the specific case. So 'Orders' are only an example.

Comment: Mmmm, then I think I'd want to go with some form of 1, but re-use the 'actual' tables as much as possible.  So, you should probably use the `product` table, and just have a `purchaseTemplate` table, etc.  Definitely don't go with 2 - if you forget about the flag column in some queries, you could be in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I think that  you are thinking of the problem the wrong way.  What you should be doing is
creating a product bundle that meets the needs of a small business customer.

So you can add self-joining table between products

Product-Bundle   table

Product-ID1 integer  not null references  product ( product_id) 
Product_ID2 integer  not null check( !=  Product-ID1 ) references  product ( product_id)

primary key ( Product-ID1 , Product_ID2  )
qty integer not null check ( > 0 )
....

Now you can create a product table entry  that references the product table for its constituent products

Comment: Hi. So do you mean a self-referencing table and then Bill-Of-Materials (BOM)? If you look at my comment to the question, you see that I am talking about a multi-table 'Bundle': Do you propose a new self-referencing table to all the other relevant tables too? How do I get them interrelated?